# How to work with multidimensional vector in R?

Tags: arrays, r, vector, syntax

i don't find it in anywhere. 
how i can do this in R:

```
a = [1,2,'full',array(5,6,7)];
echo a[4][1] #6
```

Comment: Surely `a[4][1]` is either 5 if you use 1-indexing or an index error on the first index (`[4]`) if you use 0-indexing? Or is this some mad language that mixes 1-indexing and 0-indexing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its called a "list" in R, and everything is indexed from 1:

```
> a = list(1,2,'full',c(5,6,7))
> a[[4]][1]
[1] 5
```

The list is the basic structure for anything unstructured. R does have vectors, matrices, multidimensional arrays, but the list is what you use to build anything non-rectangular.

Note there are no scalars, just vectors of length 1...

Comment: Nice, my prob was accessing the data. The brackets positions are quite different. thks!